# Is there a way to get the Github Pull Request number during a build of Google Cloud Build?

Tags: google-cloud-build

During a Google Cloud Build, is there a way to get information regarding the fact that the build is associated with a Pull Request like the Pull Request number/id for example?

It seems that no such substitution variable is available for the moment ref: https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GitHub, a single branch can be associated with multiple Pull Requests.

You can look up all PRs associated with a given branch ref using the GitHub API: https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/

Cloud Build does not currently provide the Pull Request information, but if it did this would probably come from something like the [Check Suite](https://developer.github.com/v3/checks/suites/#response) data, which also treats PRs as a list.

Comment: Thank you very much for the pointers. Actually, I think that as for the moment the GCB Github App doesn't support PR events I will have to hack and hope (or/and detect) that branch will only match one PR.

Answer (score 2):

Now they are available as CloudBuild environment variables. From the official document:

> Cloud Build provides the following GitHub-specific default
> substitutions available for pull request triggers:
>
> ```
> $_HEAD_BRANCH : head branch of the pull request
> $_BASE_BRANCH : base branch of the pull request
> $_HEAD_REPO_URL : url of the head repo of the pull request
> $_PR_NUMBER : number of the pull request
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Not from Github API, but you can get the PR# from command line:

```sh
$ hub pr list -f "%I%n" -h "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"
12345
```

Source: This [blog post](https://blog.junjizhi.com/all/technical/2020/05/24/git-command.html).